# how to route between different pages in a website using django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to build a website to practice wherein i want to make a home page in which there will be two categories in a horizontal direction, lets name them "windows" and "linux" , i simply want to show text about windows when a user clicks on windows button and text about linux when a user clicks on linux button. As per my knowledge i need to create two apps called windows and linux with their respective template file and a master template file in rot folder that will work like hompage , however i am unable to put all together as im new to django. I have attached  a demo picture of how i want my  website to look like.

[image]

I only have two html files for windows and linux app, i am unable to merge it with master template file.

Answer (score 0):

To go from one page to another in Django,  one normally returns an instance of `HttpResponseRedirect` from a view. There's a shortcut called `redirect` which is easier to code. For example, in a class-based `FormView`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    # do stuff
    return HttpResponseRedirect( 
        reverse( 'app:view_name', kwargs={
            'key': value, ...
    })

    # or,

    return redirect( 'app:view_name', key=value, ...)
```

However, if you want to navigate from one GET view to another, you simply code an `<a href="...">` in your template. So for the Widows and Linux buttons above you might put in your template

```
<a href="{% url 'myapp:view_name' key=value ... %}">
   <button type="button" class="css-class">Linux</button>
</a>
```

And clicking the button will link you to the page that's being served by the
Django app called `myapp` with an url called `view_name` that has keyword
arguments as specified in the `{%url` tag.

(To start with while learning, you can simply hardcode the href rather than using `{% url ...` )

Unless this is the start of something much larger, you don't need two apps, or even two views. You could do it all with one `TemplateView` with an `os` kwarg to say which set of information to display in the bottom panel.

```
path( 'home', MyView.as_view(), name='home'),
path( 'os/<str:os>',   MyView.as_view(), name='osview')
```

and in the view, find out whether self.kwargs['os'] exists (if not, a home view) and if it does, it will say whether to display windows or linux information.